# Are questions about Hideo Kojima considered off-topic?

Tags: discussion, tags

Yesterday I noticed that we don't have a [hideo-kojima](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hideo-kojima) tag on this site. He's a very well known game designer who's worked on several sci-fi and fantasy titles, including (all emphasis mine):

### [Snatcher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snatcher_(video_game))

> The setting and story of Snatcher are heavily **influenced by cyberpunk and science-fiction media**, taking place in a large **futuristic** dystopian city. The story revolves around an investigator named Gillian Seed assigned to investigate a breed of **bioroids** known as "snatchers", who are killing humans and taking their place in society.

### [Metal Gear Solid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_Gear_Solid)

> The year is 2005 *(the game was released in 1998)*, six years after the downfall of Zanzibarland. A renegade **genetically-enhanced special forces unit**, FOXHOUND, has seized a remote island in Alaska's Fox Archipelago codenamed "Shadow Moses", the site of a nuclear weapons disposal facility. FOXHOUND threatens to use the **nuclear-capable mecha, Metal Gear REX**, against the U.S. government if they do not receive the remains of Big Boss and the ransom of $1 billion within 24 hours. Solid Snake is forced out of retirement by Colonel Roy Campbell to infiltrate the island and neutralize the threat.

### [Zone of the Enders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zone_of_the_Enders)

> The Zone of the Enders series is **set in the late 22nd century. Mankind has colonized Mars, and space colonies are also set up in orbit around Jupiter.** Fueling this expansion are two scientific advances: the development of the Laborious Extra-Orbital Vehicle, or LEV, a **mecha** used for labor and military use, and the discovery of Metatron, a high-energy ore found on Callisto.

---

We have several questions about [J.R.R. Tolkien](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/j-r-r-tolkien), [J.K. Rowling](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jk-rowling), and [Isaac Asimov](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/isaac-asimov), but none about Kojima, and he's only ever *mentioned* in [one answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/112916/75000) to one question.

**So are questions about him and his career considered off-topic? Has he not contributed enough to the genres?**

Comment: No tags just mean nobody's gotten around to creating one yet, or nobody's asked about the thing yet. :)

Answer (score 6):

Tags for works should exist separately from tags for authors. In general, we try to use author tags [only for questions about their lives](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7924/70236), or overarching themes in their works (or maybe their style).

> If the question is asking about a) aspects of the author's life, or b) aspects of the author's work that are not specific to a single work or franchise, then we tag the question with the name of the author.

Thus an author may already be present on this site, even without a dedicated tag. Their works don't need to be tagged with the author tag, unless for reasons listed in linked meta.

**If you can make a good case <sup>1</sup>  for a question about Hideo Kojima being on-topic** - maybe you'll ask where he got the inspiration for the newest game, *Death Stranding* (just an example, maybe not a good one) - **create the tag and ask away** (you have the needed rep to create a tag).

<sup>1</sup>  Said case better be really good, because the line between off-topic and on-topic for questions about authors [is thin](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11125/70236). Looking at [Kojima's Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hideo_Kojima#Works), most if not all his works seem to be SFF-related, but not every question about Kojima is a good fit for this site. [Rand's answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11129/70236) suggests a heuristic:

> Is it justifiably connected to an SF/F work?

which I think makes sense. An even [older meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9531/70236) explicitly marks fandom-related questions as on-topic, even if hardly connected to an SFF work.

Comment: Okay. I wasn't sure if there was already a consensus on his standing in our community.

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd - there probably just hasn't been an interest.  Video game fans tend to focus on Arqade rather than here.