# What is the scope of fandom information?

Tags: discussion, scope

#### **Reminder**: Please don't VTRO or bring the "meta effect" onto the linked question until a consensus is reached about the true scope of fandom information.

---

From the [Help Center > Asking](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> ## What topics can I ask about here?
>
> Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange is for questions targeted towards science fiction and fantasy enthusiasts. This includes questions about:
>
> - Plot, character, or setting explanations
> - Historical or societal context of a work
> - Behind-the-scenes **and fandom information**
> - Story identification
> - Franchise/series reading or viewing order

So, fandom information is clearly on topic but can we clarify the scope of it?

---

This question has mainly come about after I saw [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/190304/58193) (currently closed), the discussion in its comments and [its timeline](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/190304/timeline):

- Close review: Leave Open x 3
- Close review: Leave Open x 3
- Close review: Close × 2, Leave Open × 1

After a read of the question I would probably agree it's off topic. It's not related to the work apart from a group of friends, who all are/were a part of the same show, going to a wedding. However, should it actually be on topic? Where do we draw the line with fandom information?

---

Just to clarify my question is the general title "What is the scope of fandom information?" I am just using the linked question as a recent example of something that was clearly dividing the community.

Comment: Related reading: [Should questions about fandom response be on-topic?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11785/58193) and [Why is fandom information treated as if it weren't on topic?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9529/58193).

Comment: I'm not sure I *like* the question, but I don't think it's off-topic either.  If we're going to permit questions about the creators of fictional works, it's reasonable that this includes actors, even if my personal preference is that I'd rather see interest towards writers and other core visionaries instead of anything I could find on a million celebrity gossip columns.

Comment: @Radhil The point about that question isn't really related to the SFF-nal work. It's more about celebrity gossip as you say. But the point of this meta question to define the scope in a general manner; that question just prompted me to ask.

Comment: no, it's not *directly* related to *Game of Thrones*, but with the context of creating the TV adaptation, bringing those two actors together is very easily part of the history of the show.  This isn't even really a fandom thing (unless the show just gave the fandom that impression?).  But to address what you want, I guess the scope should roughly be, fandom reactions, interpretations, misrepresentations, related to the work/creator they're fans of, but not to include any random/parallel topic of interest to those members.... does that sound like English? It's early yet.

Comment: @Radhil I sort of understand what you mean but I'm not 100% sure. Some things sound like they should probably be off topic but I don't know.

Comment: I don't know what the scope of content creators questions are either, but it seems to me they should be the same. Questions about motivation, influences and writing/acting styles seem on topic. Questions about what they do in their personal lives seem off topic. "Did being a climber change the way Isaac Hempstead Wright played Bran Stark" seems ok. "Does Isaac Hempstead Wright go to this fab nightclub in Hackney" would not.

Comment: @Jontia That seems like a perfectly reasonable line to draw.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - And yet they hated my "was Tolkien a driver" question, despite my linking it directly to his writings.

Comment: @Valorum never seen it.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - It [sleeps with the fishes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/141084/was-tolkien-a-driver)

Comment: @Valorum, relating it to Mr Bliss would've been a better idea. The connection to your writings is _incredibly_ weak.

Comment: "*Reminder: Please don't VTRO or bring the "meta effect" onto the linked question*" - good try :-) Unfortunately, the meta effect can't be so easily prevented.

Comment: @Randal'Thor No, hence why it went from a small footer to a large heading

Comment: Could you provide a basic definition of what is meant by "fandom information"? I thought it meant information about science-fiction and fantasy **fandom**, i.e., fan conventions, fan organizations, fan awards, fanzines, etc. It's not clear to me why some commenters and the answer below are bringing u questions about **actors**.

Comment: @user14111 Well that is essentially what this question is asking.

Answer (score 17):

The scope of SFF Stack Exchange is set out on the main tour page.

> Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for science fiction and fantasy enthusiasts. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about science fiction or fantasy.

In the context of this question, the key phrase is "about science fiction or fantasy". This means Questions about motivation, influences and writing/acting styles would on topic. Questions about what they do in their personal lives, unless it can be specifically linked to a work of SF&F, should be off topic.

To provide examples;
"Did being a climber change the way Isaac Hempstead Wright played Bran Stark" - On Topic
"Does Isaac Hempstead Wright go to this fab nightclub in Hackney" - Off Topic

I don't see any reason for fandom questions to have a different on-topic scope than questions about authors. The scope of author questions came up previously; [pulled from a comment](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11125/why-are-these-joke-question-answer-allowed)

Comment: Given the theme you've decided to follow, I thought I'd point out, one of our active moderators has raised the same point [previously](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11125/why-are-these-joke-question-answer-allowed) and it garnered 22 upvotes. You might find it interesting, he raises some good points.

Comment: Thanks for the link it seems we've followed the same thought process. Reading through the comments at the bottom, the idea that popular isn't the same as good comes to mind.

Comment: Would "Did Isaac Hempstead Wright go to this fab nightclub in Hackney's Game of Thrones Trivia Night" be on topic?

Comment: @ArcanistLupus No, I don't believe so. That question would be "about" Isaac, not about SF&F. I might let it pass if it asked if it was rumored that he'd done badly and you wanted to know if he spoilers he'd learned while filming caused him to get current canon questions wrong.